# Password change C

Tags: c, passwords

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to figure it out why my password doesn't change. I tried moving pin=1234; in main(void) but that doesn't do anything. Any ideas how can I do this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 
void getPin();
void changePin();

int main(void)
{
    getPin();
}

void getPin()
{
    int pin;
    pin=1234;
    int findPin;
    printf("What is the pin?: ");
    scanf("%d", &findPin);
    int x=1;
    while(x=1)
    {
    if (findPin == pin) 
        {
        printf("\nAcces granted\n");
        changePin();
        break;
        }
    else
        {
        printf("\nAcces denied\n");
        printf("What is the pin?: ");
        scanf("%d", &findPin);
        x=1;
        }
    }
}

void changePin()
{
    int pin;
    int newPin;
    printf("\nEnter new pin: ");
    scanf("%d", &newPin);
    pin = newPin;
    printf("\nThe new pin is: %d\n", pin);

    getPin();
}
```

I'm guessing that after the pin is changed it goes again to pin=1234 because that is his initial value. But how can I change that to not have my initial pin to 1234?

Comment: You do know the difference between assignment with `=` and comparison for equality with `==`? I wonder because your loop `while (x = 1)`.

Comment: Also, you do know that different variables in different scopes (like different functions) are unrelated to each other, even if they have the same name?

Comment: Yes but if I declare pin=1234  in getPin() after the password is changed it's gonna take again the value 1234. What should I do to prevent taking the value 1234 after is changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you can't save the new pin is that you are assigning 1234 to "pin" variable every time you enter the getPin() function. And you are calling getPin() after changing the password in changePin().

Make "pin" a global variable and you are good to go.

Your code has another issue with you while statement. `=` is the assignment operator. What you want to do is `while(1)`.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void getPin();
void changePin();

int pin = 1234; // Default pin

int main(void)
{
    getPin();
}

void getPin()
{
    int findPin;
    printf("What is the pin?: ");
    scanf("%d", &findPin);
    while(1)
    {
    if (findPin == pin)
        {
        printf("\nAcces granted\n");
        changePin();
        break;
        }
    else
        {
        printf("\nAcces denied\n");
        printf("What is the pin?: ");
        scanf("%d", &findPin);
        }
    }
}

void changePin()
{
    int newPin;
    printf("\nEnter new pin: ");
    scanf("%d", &newPin);
    pin = newPin;
    printf("\nThe new pin is: %d\n", pin);

    getPin();
}
```

Here is a sample output:

```
What is the pin?: 1234

Acces granted

Enter new pin: 5555

The new pin is: 5555
What is the pin?: 1235

Acces denied
What is the pin?: 1234

Acces denied
What is the pin?: 55555

Acces denied
What is the pin?: 5555

Acces granted

Enter new pin: 3333

The new pin is: 3333
What is the pin?: 5555

Acces denied
What is the pin?: 1234

Acces denied
What is the pin?: 3333

Acces granted
```

Hope this helps.

Baris